# Java RMI- unexpected behavior of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, rmi

I'm new to java rmi and I have issues with synchronization.

The server handles a small data base throw files (7 files,each one represents an university),

the client when connected gives the name of the university then chooses an option :

- add a student
- remove a student
- update a student
- search for a student

Everything works fine, but I have a problem with synchronization.It doesn't work the way I expected.

Say we have 3 files, I created 3 private static Integers to use like this

```
public class CarnetImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Carnet {

    private String fac;
    private static Integer univ1=1;
    private static Integer univ2=1;
    private static Integer univ3=1;

    CarnetImpl(String fac) throws RemoteException {
        this.fac=fac;
    }
    public  void add(Student e) throws RemoteException {
        Integer lock=1
        switch (fac){
            case "univ1":
            lock=univ1;
            break;

            case "univ2":
            lock=univ2;
            break;

            case "univ3":
            lock=univ3;
            break;
        } 
        synchronized(lock){
            //creating a file named "fac.txt" (fac can be univ1,2 or3) and adding a student
        }
    }
}
```

I did the same thing for the other methods.

What I expected is that for a given university only one client can use a method,while more than one client can use the same method for different universities at the same time.

But after testing it seems that even for different universities a client have to wait for an other to finish to use the method.

**Example :**

Client 1 asks the server to add student1 to univ1 (i added a 5' sleep and a println to detect threads behavior ).

Before the end of the 5 seconds client 2 asks the server to add(or any other method) student2 to univ2.

As client2 asked an add on univ2,I expected that lock will take univ2 so the thread wouldn't wait because univ2 is not locked unlike univ1.

Can anyone help me understand ?

Any suggestions to get the expected behavior would be most welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static Integer univ1=1;
private static Integer univ2=1;
private static Integer univ3=1;
```

These are three references to the one and the same object, the `Integer` instance from that class's internal cache of all values between -128 and 128.

You would have avoided this if you kept to the recommended practice to use plain `Object`s for locks.

I should also comment that your whole design is needlessly roundabout: since `fac` is fixed at instantiation time, you would be better off assigning the proper lock object to an instance variable at that point instead of going through the decision cascade on each method call.